# How to read each file in the same folder matched by the file names entered in a range of cells (excel)? And do the same action to all files?

Tags: excel, vba, file, directory

I have a wks that contains a table with headers "File Name" and "Count".

"File Name" column is pre-filled with names of files that i expect to be in the same dir folder.

I want to create a vba code that can automatically count the number of entries in column A for each of those files - named in "File Name" column and return the count under the "Count" column in the respective row of that file name. There will be no gaps in between the data.

All of these file names specified in the Excel exist in the same folder.

For example:
c:\path...\TestFolder
Contains all the files that are named in the worksheet

Under the "File Name" column in the worksheet, i have "Test1" in cell A3, "The Next Test" in cell A4...

I want the vba to allow user to pick folder location (c:\path...\TestFolder) and if "Test1" exist in the "TestFolder", count how many entries are in column A of "Test1", return answer under column titled "Count" in cell B3. Continue to the next file in the "File Name" column, which is "The Next Test" in cell A4. Return count to B4 etc.

These files are all in .csv format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

This is Excel vba.
I have tried looking for solution but not managed to find any online. and the ask seems quite complex.

```
Dim Path, myPath As String
Dim FileName, MsgStr As String
Dim lastRow, lastRowMas As String
Dim extractDate As String
Dim enteredName As String
Dim C As Range
Dim Wkb As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'user interface to pick folder location
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo CleanEnd
            myPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

For Each C In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:A10")
    If C.Value2 = "" Then
        If MsgStr = "" Then
'still working on the messaging for any missing file
        End If
    End If
Loop

'enteredName is what under "File Name" (A5) in range A6:A10

'open files that exist in the folder selected
FileName = Dir(myPath & "\" & enteredName &".csv", vbNormal)
Do Until FileName = ""
    Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=myPath & "\" & FileName)
    For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets   'state actions below
        'get count of used cells in column A
        'enter count of used cells in MasterSheet - same row as the name column, in column named "Count"
    Next WS
    Wkb.Close False
    FileName = Dir()
Loop    'next file and actions
```

i expect the out up is one button operate, running code that will automatically read all listed files in the selected folder and return each of the count of entries in the respective row in the column named "Count".

Comment: Note that `Dim Path, myPath As String` only declares `myPath As String` but `Path As Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim Path As String, myPath As String` otherwise it is `Variant` by default. Same for your other `Dim` statements.

Comment: What is a `used cell`?  There are various `count` functions you could use.  Or find the last cell used in that column.  What about blanks within the range?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ noted. Thanks!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld used cells refers to cells in the Mastersheet (sheet that is runnin the vba on) that are filled. And as mentioned, there are no gaps within that range/ that column in the source (refers to the files I am trying the load).
thanks

Comment: But your code indicates you are wanting the count of `used cells in column A` for each worksheet in the workbooks you are opening.  Can't you simply use the `counta` property of the `worksheetfunction` object?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i wanted to count the number of cells that are filled in column A for each of the files listed in the master sheet, under the column named "File Name".
Perhaps I'm not explaining it properly, please excuse me as I am quite new to vba.
Any advise on how this can be done/ modification of my code to make it work would be greatly appreaciated. thanks

Comment: As I wrote, the `counta` function might give you what you want.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I am not sure how that is used. could you put it in my code to show me how that integrates together? - I suspect my code wouldnt run because i have been piecing many resources together and not know how to optimise it.